# Reshaping array to recombine array tiles

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I've used `from skimage.util import view_as_windows` to convert an 10 channel array into a series of patches:

```
step = 2
window = 10
window_shape = (window, window, image.shape[2])
patches = view_as_windows(image, (window, window, image.shape[2]), step=step)
```

This produces a shape `(106, 43, 1, 10, 10, 10)` which I reshape into `(4558, 10, 10, 10)` since I want to prepare data for an image classifier via:

`output = patches.reshape((-1,) + window_shape)`

How can I convert the image patches which have a shape `(4558, 10, 10, 10)` back into the original image array?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something from the question, but can't you use `reshape`?

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(106, 43, 1, 10, 10, 10)
print(X.shape)

X = X.reshape(4558, 10, 10, 10)
print(X.shape)

X = X.reshape(106, 43, 1, 10, 10, 10)
print(X.shape)
```

Output:

```
(106, 43, 1, 10, 10, 10)
(4558, 10, 10, 10)
(106, 43, 1, 10, 10, 10)
```